# Change monthly data to daily data and spread out values over each day of that month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, converters

I have a df with monthly data:

```
date       | type   | value1 | value2 
2020-04-01 | "a"    | 30     | 60     
2020-04-01 | "b"    | 60     | 120    
2020-04-01 | "c"    | 45     | 180    
...        | ...    | ...    | ...    
2021-02-01 | "a"    | 28     | 56    
2021-02-01 | "b"    | 21     | 42   
2021-02-01 | "c"    | 5.6    | 16.8
```

I need to get daily data for each month.
Each value1 and value2 should be spread out evenly for every month.

If the month has 30 days = "value1 / 30" and "value2 / 30" for each day in that month.
If the month has 28 days = "value1 / 28" and "value2 / 28" for each day in that month.

Same for 31 days.

End dataframe should be:

```
    date   | type | value1 | value2 
2020-04-01 | "a"  | 1      | 2     # 30 days in April 2020
2020-04-02 | "a"  | 1      | 2
2020-04-03 | "a"  | 1      | 2
...        | ...  | ..
2020-04-01 | "b"  | 2      | 4     # 30 days in April 2020
2020-04-02 | "b"  | 2      | 4
2020-04-03 | "b"  | 2      | 4
...        | ...  | ..
2020-04-01 | "c"  | 1.5    | 3     # 30 days in April 2020
2020-04-02 | "c"  | 1.5    | 3
2020-04-03 | "c"  | 1.5    | 3
...        | ...  | ..
2021-02-01 | "a"  | 1      | 2     # 28 days in February 2021
2021-02-02 | "a"  | 1      | 2
2021-02-03 | "a"  | 1      | 2
...        | ...  | ..
2021-02-01 | "b"  | 0.75   | 1.5     # 28 days in February 2021
2021-02-02 | "b"  | 0.75   | 1.5
2021-02-03 | "b"  | 0.75   | 1.5
...        | ...  | ..
2021-02-01 | "c"  | 0.2    | 6     # 28 days in February 2021
2021-02-02 | "c"  | 0.2    | 6
2021-02-03 | "c"  | 0.2    | 6
```

How can I do this with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add days by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and then divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with number of days for each month by [`daysinmonth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.daysinmonth.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
rng = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(), name='date')

df = df.set_index('date').reindex(rng, method='ffill')
df = df.div(df.index.daysinmonth, axis=0).reset_index()

print (df)
          date    value1    value2
0   2020-04-01  1.000000  2.000000
1   2020-04-02  1.000000  2.000000
2   2020-04-03  1.000000  2.000000
3   2020-04-04  1.000000  2.000000
4   2020-04-05  1.000000  2.000000
..         ...       ...       ...
329 2021-02-24  0.714286  1.071429
330 2021-02-25  0.714286  1.071429
331 2021-02-26  0.714286  1.071429
332 2021-02-27  0.714286  1.071429
333 2021-02-28  0.714286  1.071429

[334 rows x 3 columns]
```

EDIT: Solution for `reindex` per `type` column separately with custom lambda function:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

f = (lambda x: x.set_index('date')
                .reindex(pd.date_range(x['date'].min(), 
                                       x['date'].max() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(), 
                                       name='date'), method='ffill'))
df = (df.groupby('type').apply(f)
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
       .set_index('type', append=True))

df = df.div(df.index.get_level_values(0).daysinmonth, axis=0, level=0).reset_index()
print (df)
           date type    value1    value2
0    2020-04-01    a  0.033333  0.066667
1    2020-04-02    a  0.033333  0.066667
2    2020-04-03    a  0.033333  0.066667
3    2020-04-04    a  0.033333  0.066667
4    2020-04-05    a  0.033333  0.066667
        ...  ...       ...       ...
997  2021-02-24    c  0.007143  0.214286
998  2021-02-25    c  0.007143  0.214286
999  2021-02-26    c  0.007143  0.214286
1000 2021-02-27    c  0.007143  0.214286
1001 2021-02-28    c  0.007143  0.214286
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to have every day of a month as a row as shown in the end df example.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I forgot to add that there is a type column with ~18 different values for every month (changed df + df end result accordingly). I need to add days for the months for every type column and your solution gives me "cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or a list". If you know the solution to this, would you be so kind to change your answer? Sorry for the trouble.